# git Error when Pushing Branch: Authentication failed: syntax error near unexpected token ')'

Tags: git, azure-devops

In git, when trying to push a branch from my local machine to origin, I am using this command:

```
git push origin MSMQtoAzure
```

I am then prompted for my VSO user id and password, which I enter.  I know the creds are valid because I use them all the time.  But, I get this in the command prompt:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for <url>
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ')'
bash: command substitution: line 1: '__git_ps1)'
```

Here's the entire contents of my git.config file (with some sensitive parts removed)

```
[core]
    bare = false
    filemode = false
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<redacted>.com/defaultcollection/Response%20(Git)/_git/Main
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "origin"]
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
[branch "master"]
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "LeadSubmission"]
    remote = origin
[branch "LeadSubmission"]
    merge = refs/heads/LeadSubmission
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 887x427+1984+334 369 192
[branch "ChangeXToY"]
    remote = origin
[branch "ChangeXToY"]
    merge = refs/heads/ChangeXToY
[branch "MSMQtoAzure"]
    remote = origin
[branch "MSMQtoAzure"]
    merge = refs/heads/MSMQtoAzure
```

**EDIT:**

My password has a $ sign in it.  Might that be the issue?  I've tried to escape it.  Say the password is 123$456.  I've tried all of the following:

- 123/$456
- 123\$456
- 123`$456

Comment: Only an idea.. what happens when you're using %28 for ( and %29 for ) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean

Comment: It's weird (but harmless) that your config has an extra `[remote "origin"]` section.  As for the error, I wonder if that's coming from something to do with the URL passed to the https authenticator, which contains `%20` for a space but literal parentheses for parentheses.  I don't know enough about this https authenticator to say for sure.

Comment: I wondered that too, so I looked up how to url encode a ( and  ).  Turns out, you don't.  They just stay ( and )

Comment: Looking closer, I see both errors are coming from bash; I'd check into .bashrc settings.

Comment: I have no idea what that means!  But I'll look into it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Personal Access Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/code/git/command-prompt#GetsetuptousethecommandprompttoolsCreateapersonalaccesstokenforyourVisualStudioTeamServicesaccount) or [Alternate Authentication](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/auth/overview) when use VSO Git Repo from Git Command Prompt.

For convenience, You can install [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows). It will prompt a VSO login dialog then you can enter your VSO username and password directly.